# A fatal error has occured - 553789

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, windows-server

My site is an e-commerce website. It was working well on old server(Windows/IIS 7) until the client migrated it another server(Windows).I get 'A fatal error has occured - 553789' error with white screen when I click on the 'Add to Cart button' on the new server. I tried to convince the client to change to Linux server with Apache for better performance and hoped that this will solve the issue. But he is not interested to change it :(.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful to have some kind of information about your code.

Comment: what it has to do with code?? I mean the site worked well on old server, but have issue with the new server...

Comment: You should be more descriptive. What is your commerce plugin ?

Comment: in wordpress, enable debug in wp-config.php file and post the error

Comment: @Tamil Selvan -tried it solved the warnings.no luck still:(

Comment: @newCodex what wordpress eCommerce plugin used and r u used ssl for site

Comment: @ Merianos Nikos @Tamil Selvan -Actually,there is no e commerce plugin installed. E-commerce functionality is present as part of the theme which was developed by the ones who first got the site.This is a maintenance site with us and seriously speaking it looks like the site was developed  many years back using PHP4. No SSL activated.

Comment: The error is coming from some part of your code, which happens to work on the old server.

Comment: @Tamil Selvan - checked error log of IIS. No warning message shown.